# Ionic: Failed to build android

Tags: android, ionic-framework

Having huge issues trying to build to android with Ionic. I tried initially the normal `ionic build android`, it failed with

```
[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.]
```

I did some hunting around stack overflow and ionic forums, and installed Java and Android Studio as a 'solution', it began to install lots of .jar files, and this happened:

```
 Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar


    Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-codec-1.4.jar


    Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/external/lombok/lombok-ast/0.2.3/lombok-ast-0.2.3.jar


    Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/abego/treelayout/org.abego.treelayout.core/1.0.1/org.abego.treelayout.core-1.0.1.jar




    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
    > failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: /Users/.../Library/Android/sdk

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.


    BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 51.558 secs

    Error: /users/nick/documents/.../.../platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
    > failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: /Users/.../Library/Android/sdk

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    Please install Android target: "android-23".

    Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: /Users/.../Library/Android/sdk/tools/android
    You will require:
    1. "SDK Platform" for android-23
    2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
    3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)
```

Any advice? Maybe I need to un-install Android Studio or something? I'm very bad at this, as you likely can tell. But this is hugely holding back the project I'm working on, so will be amazing if someone could help!

Comment: Are using windows or Mac or linux ?

Comment: @ahlem-jarrar Mac, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base from [Installing the Android Development Environment](http://spring.io/guides/gs/android/)

Configure the **ANDROID_HOME** environment variable based on the location of the Android SDK. Additionally, consider adding **ANDROID_HOME/tools**, and **ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools** to your PATH.

For Mac :

```
   export ANDROID_HOME=/<installation location>/android-sdk-macosx
  export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

For windows :

```
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\<installation location>\android-sdk-windows
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

For linux :

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/<installation location>/android-sdk-linux
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Comment: Okay, I think I have these set already though: ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Nick/Library/Android/sdk

JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: Still got the error: rror: /users/nick/documents/.../applications/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: /Users/Nick/Library/Android/sdk

Comment: click on the link written in the error: Open Android SDK Manager
and it will show dialog that will help you to install the sdk required to your project.

Comment: I tried this, now I'm getting: getActivity().requestPermissions(permissions, mappedRequestCode);
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
error: cannot find symbol
            int result = activity.checkSelfPermission(permission);
error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: I got it working by updating android inside the folder with cordova update platform android. thanks for the help!